# Facebook ql asks for indexable column in where clause when it is indexable itself

Tags: facebook-graph-api, get, facebook-fql

I have tried the following FQL in Facebook:

```
SELECT checkin_id FROM checkin WHERE author_uid = me()
```

[Test this query](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/270849796387714/?fql=SELECT%20checkin_id%20FROM%20checkin%20WHERE%20author_uid%20%3D%20me())

However, I get the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql ", 
    "type": "NoIndexFunctionException", 
    "code": 604
  }
}
```

But [checkin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/checkin) is marked as indexable in the documentation.

Now what can be done?

Comment: Submit a bug report https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=SELECT%20checkin_id%20FROM%20checkin%20WHERE%20author_uid%3Dme() works fine for me.

Comment: CBroe can you please describe your permissions?

Comment: @CBroe you are right! It works there! Please write it as answer, I have to accept it. :O

Comment: THankyou @phwd, I have filed a bug report!